# Uniform convergence $f(x/n)*f(nx)$

Tags: uniform-convergence

I'm trying to prove the following:

> $f$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$ and $$\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = f(0) = 0.$$
>   Define $h_n(x) = f(x/n)$ and $g_n(x)= f(nx)$. Prove that $h_ng_n$ uniformly converges on $[0,\infty)$

Can you guys help me with that please?

Comment: Do you mean $h_n * g_n = h_n(x) \cdot g_n(x)$ or $h_n(g_n(x))$?

Comment: Yeah multipication.

Comment: Yeah i've tried to use the contentiousness , but it depends on x. The definition says that N should not be dependent on x.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a minor note: typically we use $*$ for convolution. For multiplication, I'll just write $h_ng_n$.

Since $g_n$ and $h_n$ converge to zero pointwise, the only viable candidate for convergence will be zero. We prove that $h_ng_n \to 0$ uniformly.

Note, since $f \to 0$ at $x=0$ or $x \to \infty$, we can find $N \in \mathbb N$ so that $\lvert f(x) \rvert \le 1$ when $x < 1/N$ or $x > N$ (why?). But $\lvert f \rvert$ has a maximum on $[1/N, N]$ since it is a continuous function on a compact set. Call this maximum $M_0$. Define $M = \max\{1, M_0\}$. Then $\lvert f(x) \rvert \le M$ for all $x \in [0,\infty)$. That is, $\lvert f \rvert$ is bounded.

Fix $\epsilon > 0$. Since $f\to 0$ at $\infty$, we can find $K_1 \in \mathbb N$ so that $t \ge K_1$ gives $$\lvert f(t)\rvert < \epsilon / M.$$ Likewise, since $f$ is continuous and $f(0) = 0$, we an find $K_2 \in \mathbb N$ so that $t \le 1/K_2$ gives $$\lvert f(t) \rvert < \epsilon / M.$$

Take $K = \max \{ K_1, K_2 \}$. Now take $x \in [0,\infty)$ and $n \ge K$. If $x \in [0,1]$, then $x/n \le 1/K \le 1/K_2$ and so $\lvert f(x/n) \rvert < \epsilon / M$ But then $$h_n(x) g_n(x) < (\epsilon / M) \lvert f(nx) \rvert \le (\epsilon/M)\cdot M = \epsilon.$$  Conversely, if $x \in (1,\infty)$, then $nx > n \ge K \ge K_1$ so $\lvert f(nx) \rvert< \epsilon/M$. Then $$h_n(x) g_n(x) < \lvert f(x/n) \rvert (\epsilon / M) \le M\cdot (\epsilon/M)= \epsilon.$$ Hence for $n \ge K$, we have $\lvert h_n(x) g_n(x)\rvert < \epsilon$ for all $x \in [0,\infty)$. That is, $h_n g_n \to 0$ uniformly on $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: Thank you, that's very understandable.

Comment: A quick follow up: when you used the fact that f->0 when x->inf, you said t>K1, is this the equivalent of saying : when nx0>M where x0 is a constant? I mean does it depend on x?

Comment: You should be able to convince yourself that $K$ does not depend on $x$. In the latter analysis, the $x$ dependence is eliminated by showing that in either case $x \in [0,1]$ or $x \in (1,\infty)$, we simple use $x \le 1$ or $x > 1$ to conclude $x/n \le 1/n$ or $nx > n$. The results then only depend on $n \ge K$; not on the individual $x$ that was chosen.